# How to update recyclerView from web service periodically without leaking memory

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, android-recyclerview

My application makes a webservice call using volley, in order to update recyclerView every 10 seconds. Besides memory usage increase in 10 seconds constantly until it hits the max heap size. Then GC starts doing its job, but the memory usage does not come back down like at the beginning.
Using Eclipse MAT or Android Studio analyzer tasks, I could'nt find a single leak in my code.

I want to know that if there are suspects of leaking in my code. Any help will be appreciated.

Below I have 3 classes:

- `EventService` send a message to `MainActivity` using `sendBroadcast()` in every 10 seconds.
- `MainActiviy` will get message from `EventService` using `BroadcastReceiver` and calls `update` operation within its `Fragment`
- `EventListFragment`, which is inside the `MainActivity`, contains a `RecyclerView`, that needs to be updated.

Here is my `EventService`:

```
public class EventService extends Service {
    private volatile boolean isCanceled = false;
    public static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "connection";
    public EventService() {}

       @Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!isCanceled) {
                try {
                    Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                    AppController.getInstance().cancelPendingRequests("json_obj_req");
                    i.putExtra(KEY_MESSAGE, MESSAGE);
                    sendBroadcast(i);
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Thread eventThread = new Thread(r);
    eventThread.start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        isCanceled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here is my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Intent intent;
    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    private EventListFragment eventListFragment;
    private IntentFilter intentFilter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void setView() {
        eventListFragment = (EventListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frgEventList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        intent = new Intent(this, EventService.class);
        mReceiver = new MyReceiver(eventListFragment);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
        intent = new Intent(this, EventService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopService(intent);
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    private static class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private WeakReference<EventListFragment> eventListFragment = null;
        public MyReceiver(EventListFragment eventFragment) {
            this.eventListFragment = new WeakReference<>(eventFragment);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String mssg = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_MESSAGE);
            EventListFragment eventFragment = eventListFragment.get();
            if (mssg.equals(MESSAGE) && eventFragment != null) {
               //Update recyclerView
                eventFragment.eventToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `EventListFragment`:

```
public class EventListFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private EventAdapter eventAdapter;
    private RequestData requestData;
    private ArrayList<EventModel> eventList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event_list, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setView();
        setControl();
    }

    private void setView() {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.frg_recycler_view);
    }

    private void setControl() {
        if (eventAdapter == null && mLayoutManager == null) {
            eventList = new ArrayList<>();
            eventAdapter = new EventAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), eventList);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(eventAdapter);
        }

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemListener(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerItemListener.RecyclerTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClickItem(View v, int position) {
              EventModel model = eventList.get(position);
                SQLiteHandler db = SQLiteHandler.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                //some instances
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClickItem(View v, int position) {

            }
        }));
    }
//make service call
    public void eventToList() {
        if (requestData == null) {
            requestData = new RequestData(getActivity());
        }
        final ArrayList<EventModel> newList = new ArrayList<>(); //are you leaking?
        requestData.getEventToday(new RequestData.VolleyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject result) {
                for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject item = result.getJSONObject(Integer.toString(i));
                        EventModel eventModel = new EventModel();                
                        String title = item.getString("title");
                        String start = item.getString("start");
                        String end = item.getString("end");
                        String date = item.getString("date");
                        eventModel.setDate(date);
                        eventModel.setStartTime(start);
                        eventModel.setEndTime(end);
                        eventModel.setTitle(title);                    
                        newList.add(eventModel);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {         
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                eventAdapter.update(newList);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a design consideration: is it necessary to call web service every 10 seconds? Do you know when/how often server data changes?

Every time you read data from web server, application have to do a lot of work: you create many object, update the adapter etc. Moreover, think about network traffic, you use network every 10 seconds.

There are somethings you can do:

1. Increment wait time: in this way, you reduce the number of created object/per seconds.
2. Reduce local reference for temporary objects (see following code)
3. Check if recycler view's adapter, before add new values, the old ones was correctly deferred.
4. Evaluate if it is possible to use technology to push data, you to avoid data polling. You can see [GCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

For consideration #2, i try rewrite eventToList method:

```
public void eventToList() {
  if (requestData == null) {
    requestData = new RequestData(getActivity());
  }      
  requestData.getEventToday(new RequestData.VolleyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(JSONObject result) {
      ArrayList<EventModel> newList = new ArrayList<>();
      JSONObject item;
      EventModel eventModel;
      String title;
      String start;
      String end;
      String date;
      for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
        try {
          item = result.getJSONObject(Integer.toString(i));
          eventModel = new EventModel();                
          title = item.getString("title");
          start = item.getString("start");
          end = item.getString("end");
          date = item.getString("date");
          eventModel.setDate(date);
          eventModel.setStartTime(start);
          eventModel.setEndTime(end);
          eventModel.setTitle(title);                    
          newList.add(eventModel);
        } catch (JSONException e) {         
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      eventAdapter.update(newList);
    }
 });
```

}

Comment: 1. Could you please explain me, why should I need to increase wait time? By the way, a web service call doesn't take longer than 1-2 secs?

2. Do I have to clean the `newList` after `eventAdapter.update(newList)`?

3. The old list is always cleaned up, before I add the new one.

Comment: Base on  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846061/creating-objects-inside-loop-vs-creating-one-temp-object-before-loop) post, creating temp objects outside loop would make no huge difference.

Comment: I know that create objects outside loop make no huge difference, but everything can help, especially if it requires minimal effort.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Unfortunately I don't know how often server data changes. Will the problem be minimized, if I change wait time to 20 seconds or 30 seconds? Because my app is kind of kiosk app. It should run like "forever".

Comment: Ok, better if you bring time wait to minute or more. 30 second can be a good compromise. And remember to clean adapter's data.

Comment: So my `update` operation within adapter looks like this: `public void update(ArrayList<EventModel> list) {
        if (eventList != null) {
            eventList.clear();
            eventList.addAll(0,list);
        }
        else {
            eventList = list;
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }`. Is that what you meant to say?